# How do I set "8:00 AM" as the value of my DateTimePicker

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to set the time on my DateTimePicker value to "8:00 AM" on Form Load  (using vb.net) but can't work out how to do it.

I have tried setting the value in the properties of my DateTimePicker to "8:00 AM" but on Form Load it keeps on reverting to the current time.

Current time displayed

[image]

I have also tried setting the values on Form Load but now get error

```
DateTimePicker.Value = Date.Now("8:00 AM")
```

The error I get based on my code above is:

Expression is not an array or a method, and cannot have an argument list.

I can't work out how to set this values.

Anyone got any ideas ?

Comment: If it is always going to be 8AM, then just get the date part of `Date.Now` and add 8:00AM as default time.

Comment: please try something like `DateTimePicker.Value = New DateTime(0, 0, 0, 8, 00, 0)` also try this before it `DateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;` and let me it works or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code. it will work

```
 Dim dtval As String = "8:00 AM"
 dtppick.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dtval)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dtppick.Value = Date.Today.AddHours(8)
```

Today will give you the day with 00:00:00 as time. You can replace 8 with a variable too, which will help changing the code later.

Comment: Should be today, not now. :)

Comment: @jitendragarg tanks!

Comment: Your suggestion also works great and gives the option of even changing code easily at a later time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks to all on your contributions

This solved the problem as suggested by **Senthilkumar**

I just changed **dtppick.Value** to  **DateTimePicker.Value** to correspond with name of my control and it worked

```
 Dim Timeval As String = "8:00 AM"
 DateTimePicker.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(Timeval)
```

I tried the Suggestion made to set value like **DateTime(0, 0, 0, 8, 00, 0)** but did not work it returned an error:  **Additional information: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.**

Thanks

Comment: Thanks you Smarton

Comment: What about Mr. lomed answer

Comment: I used your suggestion before Mr. lomed posted his solution,  I just checked it now and it also gave the expected result.